# callback dock demo in Miglayout

Tags: callback, dock, miglayout

can anyone suggest where i can get a hold of the source code for the callback dock demo application in Miglayout site. such a tutorial would also be ok.  thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few broken links to where the source used to be.  Now the demos are distributed with the MiG Layout source.

1. Go to http://www.miglayout.com/
2. Follow the link under **MiGLayout Downloads** to the Downloads Folder.
3. Choose the latest version, and download the jar that includes "sources" in the name.  For instance, **miglayout-3.7.2-sources.jar**
4. Expand the jar file and locate the folder called *demo*, which includes a Java file for each of the demos.

Near the bottom of the MiG Layout page there is also a link to their support forums that look fairly active.